# A question on radar cross section of rain by using radar reflectivity factor

Tags: antenna, electromagnetism, radar

The question is one of the past exam papers of the RADAR 1 course given in TUDelft, unfortunately, solutions are not provided to the past paper yet.

The question:

> What will be the radar cross-section of the unit volume with rain at the 3GHz if the measured radar reflectivity equals to Z=10dBZ?

My attempted solution was like this:

$$
Z=10log_{10}\left(\frac{z}{[mm^6m^3]}\right)\\z=10^{10dBZ/10}mm^6m^3=10 mm^6m^3
$$

To change the units to \$m^3\$ z is multiplied by \$1\times10^{18} \$ and by using the following formula provided that \$|K|^2=0.93 \$ for water.

$$
\eta=\frac{\pi^5}{\lambda^4}\cdot |K|^2 \cdot z=\frac{\pi^5}{0.1^4}\cdot 0.93\cdot 10\cdot 1\times10^{18}=2.846\times10^{25}  
$$

My attempted solution looks incorrect and I couldn't figure out any other ways so any help would be appreciated.

[Google Drive link for slides](https://drive.google.com/file/d/12Q0Q6Fl4C0aV-E1CJVRkT8nYraT2PMNH/view?usp=sharing)